# Reconfigure/configure Tomcat logging?

Tags: tomcat, logging, configuration

I have read the documentation for Tomcat and looked online on how to do this and I can't seem to get it working. In 2010 I messed up my configuration on my production VPS with Tomcat. Largely due to a brain tumor I can not remember what I did to my Tomcat log file and I am trying to rebuild it for each of my applications configured in the `server .xml` as follows:

```
<Host appBase="webapps/buhaugane.com" name="buhaugane.com" 
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>www.buhaugane.com</Alias>
    <Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger" prefix="buhaugane" 
        suffix=".txt"  directory="logs" timestamp="true"/>
    <Context path="" docBase="buhaugane" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>

<Host appBase="webapps/thejarbar.org" name="thejarbar.org" 
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Alias>www.thejarbar.org</Alias>
    <Context path="" docBase="tjb" debug="0" directory="logs" reloadable="true"/>
    <Logger classname="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger" prefix="thejarbar" 
        suffix=".txt" directory="logs" timestamp="true"/>
</Host>
```

I have done the following in Putty on my VPS:

- `touch /opt/tomcat7/logs/buhaugane.txt`
- `touch /opt/tomcat7/logs/thejarbar.txt`
- `chown tomcat:tomcat /opt/tomcat7/logs/buhaugane.txt`
- `chown tomcat:tomcat /opt/tomcat7/logs/thejarbar.txt`

Then I restarted server and requested an erroneous rquest for a '404' anticipating log activity which failed.

This does not seem to be the correct way to configure Tomcat logging per application so how do I achieve this? Am I on the right path? I am not looking for the log4j methodology as I am trying to get my VPS to a similar state prior to illness.

Can the community assist me with this and possibly explain if Tomcat should be creating these log files for me? If yes, why is Tomcat not doing so and where can I anticipate them to be located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue. My hosting provider has outdated documentation on the location of Tomcat log files. Namely my `catalina.out` was under `var/log/tomcat7` location and nowhere under `/opt/tomcat7`.